# Why does OpenWatcom issue: Warning! W124: Comparison result always 0

Tags: c, integer-promotion, watcom

With OpenWatcom we (a colleague and myself) receive the following warning:

```
Warning! W124: Comparison result always 0
```

The code we have is of course part of a larger project, but the piece of code that results in a warning is equivalent to this:

```
typedef unsigned __int64 uint64_t; /* typedef'd depends on compiler/platform */
uint64_t x;
/* x gets a value */
if (x > 0xFFFFFFFFU) /* <-- warning */
{
    /* do something */
}
```

I would think that the literal value should be promoted to the integer type of `x`, but evidently it isn't.

What gives? Do integer promotion rules not apply to 64bit integers?

Are the only solutions an explicit cast (`(x > (uint64_t)0xFFFFFFFFU)`) or something ala comparison to `0xFFFFFFFFULL`? The typecast will actually make the warning vanish, but I didn't look at the produced code to verify that it still makes sense.

---

#### Notes:

- The code does not compile as C99, it uses something between C89 and C99 (e.g. includes C++ style single-line comments).
- Watcom and OpenWatcom are just compilers used by some of our team members and OpenWatcom was the only compiler to complain there.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: That looks like a compiler bug to me (possibly a leftover from the 32 bit version of the compiler). If the type of `x` were `unsigned int` then the warning would make sens.

Comment: try `x > 0xFFFFFFFFULL`. If it still warns, try `if (x >> 32)` of `if (x & ~0xFFFFFFFFULL)`